# Why Keep These 10 A Penny " How Long Will It Take To Program in Blah Blah Blah Language Questions" Open Yet Close This Question..?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Why keep this [question open](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/46260/how-long-would-it-take-to-learn-objective-c) and others like it open which basically asks how long does it take to learn a programming language?

[Yet I ask a valid question which basically asks](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/121875/how-seriously-would-an-employer-take-a-job-application-from-an-applicant-studyin) how esteemed is a mathematics degree from the UK open university and would software employers hire whilst you are the course.. and it gets closed

I love the advice I get from this site and I appreciate the fact that Software Technicians of all types use this site, but it's a bit shallow if you can't ask a question with a little bit of the real world involved

Comment: Good job fishing out a bad question that was still open...

Answer (score 6):

You should spent some time familiarizing yourself with the site, before forming an opinion.

You've asked a question that's clearly off topic, if you've taken the time to read the [faq](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq) as @MarkTrapp and @AnnaLear suggested you would have seen that career advice and resume help are considered off topic. And then you asked this question on the main site instead of here at meta, no worries it got migrated, but still you could have avoided it.

The guidelines of the site are simple, and if you disagree with them you can always start a meta discussion and change them, if your proposals gain enough support from the community.

**As for the specifics of your question:**

How is anyone supposed to know? The only way to get a helpful answer is from someone that were at some point in a very similar situation, but even then how could you tell if her experiences will match yours? The best that could come out of your question would be a subjective discussion, and these don't fit the QA format.

For example, I can tell you that the Open University is highly regarded in most FSTE companies, but how could I prove that I'm not just re-iterating their marketing department?

And how could anyone compare Open University to "traditional bricks and mortar university", unless you tell us which one? Cambridge University or University of Luton? If the choice is between Luton and Open employers will greatly prefer Open<sup>*</sup>.

Your question generates quite a few questions, and that's almost always a sign that [it's not a very good one](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask). But in the off chance you do get a great answer, how would that be helpful to anyone other than you? We like questions that can potentially be helpful to the community, and we don't like questions that can only be helpful to an individual. *We are not that shallow*.

**As for that "not a real question" question you fished out:**

Unfortunately there are quite a lot of those that are still open, some are just because no one else discovered them and some because in the early days of the site some subjective questions that fall under the "[bad subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)" category were allowed and even encouraged.

*After* you familiarized yourself with the site's scope and mechanics you could greatly help the site grow and evolve by searching for them and [flagging them appropriately](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/privileges/flag-posts).

<sub>* Not to badmouth the University of Luton, but a thousand years ago when I was a student in the UK its reputation was, let's say, less than stellar.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

You're right that the https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/46260/how-long-would-it-take-to-learn-objective-c question is not suitable for this site. It has now been closed.

Your question, unfortunately, isn't suitable either. As Mark Trapp said in his comment on your question, Programmers is not a career advice site and we cannot predict whether or not employers will like your education or degree.

Please check out our [FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq) to see what kind of conceptual questions about software development Programmers is about.

Answer (score 1):

Because the question is unanswerable,I might think the OU is great - my hiring manager has never heard of it.

It's too localised - it really only applies to the UK.

Should the same question be posted about every course at every institution in the world?

Comment: It's not too localised in the sense you're describing, Open University accepts applicants from all over the world, it doesn't matter where it's based.

Comment: It's exactly as localised as asking if Texas A&M is well regarded in Oshkosh

Comment: Yeap, it's localised but not because `it really only applies to the UK`. It doesn't, it's reach is potentially global, there is no location related limitations to study at the Open. Whereas a question on Texas A&M only applies to the very strict geographical regions where the various universities that comprise the system are located.

Comment: @Yannis - not that the OU is too regional, but the answer would be too regional.